# Get file type in Ruby for files without extension

Tags: ruby, fonts, postscript, file-type

I'm trying to programmatically read the file type for PostScript font files on a Mac using Ruby. The files do not have extensions, and it is possible that some are corrupt or incomplete (due to inconsistencies in how the fonts were packaged many years ago). If I inspect the file in Finder, it clearly displays the information I need:

[image]

However, I am not sure how to extract this information in Ruby. Here is what I've tried:

- Reading/parsing the file using the `File` class results in empty content
- [otfinfo](http://www.lcdf.org/type/otfinfo.1.html) returns an error: "OTF file corrupted (too small)"
- I also tried using [FileMagic](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-filemagic/versions/0.7.1), even though it is no longer maintained, but the output is not helpful, i.e.:

```
FileMagic.new.buffer(font_file) => "ASCII text, with no line terminators"
FileMagic.new(FileMagic::MAGIC_MIME).file(font_file) => "inode/x-empty; charset=binary"
```

All of this is expected behavior, because of the aforementioned issues with these files (as well as various issues with PostScript fonts in general), but I wanted to share it to be thorough in what I've already attempted.

All I want to know is how I can get that exact piece of information that is showing up in the Finder, to show up in my Ruby script. Is there some other class that can access the same thing that the Mac is using to populate the "Kind" field?

Comment: Won't be enough for your needs calling the [`file`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) unix command using [backticks](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/backtick-system-exec-in-ruby) to call it?

Comment: @AlterLagos I did try that actually, and the output is: "[Filename]: empty"